# What else can I use as CD case when I don't have a case for CD?

Tags: substitute-tool

I have many CD/DVDs without a case, because I buy empty CD/DVDs in a bundle of 25 or so. Also Many product CDs come without proper cases.

Some of the CD's plastic covers also come torn and for some the plastic cases were broken. I am not interested in buying new cases for them.

I do not want to buy an album case, as I usually rotate the CDs with friends. I cannot keep the entire album wherever I go.

How can I keep my CDs safe without damaging them?

Comment: wait, you actually have CDs? (actual suggestion: copy the content on a hard drive, and use that instead. Plus, make backups. That way, you won't be sorry when you break/scratch/lose the disc, or when it becomes suddenly unreadable for no apparent reason)